# Are Facebook Connect comments stored locally or in Facebook's DB?

Tags: api, facebook, facebook-fql

If I integrate Facebook Connect on my website so Facebook users can comment on something, will the comments have to be stored in my database or will Facebook store them for me and I pull them back when I need?

Comment: Take a glance over the API and the meager documentation. It should become apparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are stored in Facebook if you mean the XFBML comments: http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Fb:comments_%28XFBML%29

You do not need to pull them yourself, the XFBML tag does it for you.

You can see an example here: http://www.somethingtoputhere.com/commentdemo/gallery.php?picture=1